# What's my public IP over a Tor?

Tags: command-line, ip, tor

I'm attempting to figure out how to obtain the IP address that represents my connection over a tor network. What do I type into a terminal to see this information. Ultimately, I'm attempting to create an auto-log of my tor connections for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The command that you implement and most likely can in-bed into the proxychains.conf file is:

> $ curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'

If any one has any additional thoughts, they are more than welcome, they are encouraged.

Comment: I just use [icanhazip](https://icanhazip.com/) for things like this.